# what is the height for drawer menu header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Can I ask what is the standard height of the header in the Drawer
like this picture below also what is the element use in the short title, a little longer title, a very long title that will truncate is that ListItem in react-native or just Text ? also what is the margin between the icon of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design on your question follows [Google's Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html) pattern. You can read their documentation for more detail on sizing, spacing, layout etc..

You can follow this documentation and create your own components. If you are looking for ready to use components, you need to search for it since it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask for libraries and packages on SO.